# My simple rewrite rule is not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

## rule 1

```
RewriteRule ^ajax/([0-9]+)$ ajax.php?module=$1 [NC,L]
```

## rule 2

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\/\-\ñ]+)$ index.php?el9sJ6Fe%gY=$1
```

what i want is that if the url is something like:

> mysite/ajax/7

go to

> mysite/ajax.php?module=6 //or any number

and if the url is something like

> mysite/something-here/gototheindex

go to

> mysite/index.php?el9sJ6Fe%gY=chars // any charapter or any number [a-zA-Z0-9/-\ñ]

It works good for the second rule but it doesnt work for the first rule because the browser go to the ajax.php but i have a empty array in the $_GET
Thanks and sorry for bad language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure `Multiviews` is turned off. Second make sure you have the rules in the right order:

```
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^ajax/([0-9]+)$ ajax.php?module=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\/\-\ñ]+)$ index.php?el9sJ6Fe%gY=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Oh Thank you! the problem was the Options -Multiviews i put this line and now it works. thanks Jon Lin

Comment: @DamianSIlvera Yeah, if Multiviews is on, and it sees a request like `/ajax/12345` then sees that there's a file called `/ajax.php`, it'll bypass mod_rewrite and serve up `/ajax.php/12345`, which doesn't have a query string (but you'd be able to see it via `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`.

Answer (score 1):

try this instead of first rule

RewriteRule ^ajax/([0-9]+)$ ajax.php?module=$1 [PT]

Comment: Thanks for your answer radu, I tried jon's answer and it works great i didnt turn off multiviews. Thanks